# Acces prototype member in an Eventlistener

Tags: javascript, google-maps, event-handling, prototype

how can i acces a member of an object when i am in an eventlistener?.
Here is an example, i think this makes it more easier to understand ;)

```
MapProvider = function(mapID, autocompleteID) {
  // some other members
  MapProvider.prototype.map = null;
  MapProvider.prototype.autocomplete = null;

  // init function
  MapProvider.prototype.initAutocomplete = function() {  
   // some other stuff and now i create an autocompleteObj
   this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.inputField, myOptions);
   this.autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);

   // until now everything went fine
   // now i want to listen to the autocompleteObj
   // the handler is working fine aswell
   google.maps.event.addListener(this.autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
     // but now i want to acces the autocompleteObj again, but i cant :(
     // how can i access my members that i deklared in my first lines ?
     console.log(this.autocomplete.getPlace());
   });

 }
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
MapProvider = function(mapID, autocompleteID) {
    // some other members
    MapProvider.prototype.map = null;
    MapProvider.prototype.autocomplete = null;

    // init function
    MapProvider.prototype.initAutocomplete = function() {  

        this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.inputField, myOptions);
        this.autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);

        var _this = this;

        google.maps.event.addListener(this.autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {

            console.log(_this.autocomplete.getPlace());
        });

    }
}
```